# Doctrine Query Builder: match all values

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, where-clause, query-builder

i have following query:

```
$filters is an array like this array('black', 'green', '50mm')

$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('d')
        ->select('product', 'attribute')
        ->from('TwndleBackendBundle:Product', 'product')
        ->innerJoin('product.attributeValues', 'attribute')
        ->where('attribute.value IN (:value)')
        ->setParameter('value', $filters)
        ->getQuery();
```

this works fine. but i need to make that doctrine returns only the products that have ALL these filters instead of just one

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately you can pass an array:

```
    public function findUsersByIdArray(array $usersIds)
    {
      if (count($usersIds) === 0) {
        return null;
      }

      $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();
      $query = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
        ->addSelect('user')
        ->from("UserBundle:User", 'user')
        ->andWhere("user.id  in (:usersIds)")
        ->setParameter('usersIds', $usersIds)
        ->getQuery();
      $result = $query->getResult();
      return $result;

     }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('d')
        ->select('product', 'attribute')
        ->from('TwndleBackendBundle:Product', 'product')
        ->innerJoin('product.attributeValues', 'attribute')
        ->where('attribute.value ALL (:value)')
        ->setParameter('value', $filters)
        ->getQuery();
```

Se also: [**Subqueries with ALL**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/all-subqueries.html)

Comment: Attempting to use 'ALL' as described here gives my this error: "Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'ALL' "